# Proxying Rest Services

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, architecture

I have several backends services (rest+soap) that have to be cosumed by an SPA (Angula 2 App).

As JWT is not feasible for me for the moment , security is done using CAS.

In order to avoid CORS and to have security in one place I am thinking on creating a layer which will be accessible directly by the client and from that layer to call the each rest call. Somenthing like a proxy ,who will just pass thorought the client requests.

Do you see any disadvantage to this solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, if you do it properly. Such proxy is called API-Gateway, and there alot of practices about what to do with/what do not with it.

Such practice is necessary one when system use Micro-service architecture.

And, if done properly it considered to be good practice.
It could implement CAS, and proxy requests to the inner system services adding requester metadata to the request headers for services to consume and use in their flows.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/